# What to do after writing the user requirements document?

Tags: java, database, architecture

Suppose I have to develop a **Desktop Application** using Java SE. I have finished writing *User requirements document*. In this document, I mentionned the functionnalities of my futur application. I analysed the needs of the user and established *What* the ideal application has to perform.

Now, I have to **conceive the architecture** of the application and ddetailled conception of the app. This is what I don't know how to do ?

I have an idea, which is as follow : elaborate a use case diagram, then for every use case, make an sequence diagram finally produce a class diagram from which I can generate the code.

Is this correct ? How about using a **database management system** at which level I add the use of DBMS ? from the first uml diagramme ?

please any help is a welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well you know the functions you will implement and you know the requirements. While at this point you should know or infer some database  requirements you don't have the whole picture yet. If you want to do an iterative software development you can start with whatever you feel you got more to progress with, then go back to your other tasks and work in increments. Because you are doing an iterative process you will be erasing bits here and there, polishing your work as you go.

To work sequentially, you'd finish all the analysis documentation before doing design, and that before touching code. Initial databases can be generated from java classes (beans), so that's when that comes in.

Under your chosen methodology the wiki link you provided lists what it is expected to be done in order. For the part of high level design, which you claim to have problems with, you'll want the appropriate UML diagrams, use components for modules/software architecture.

Because it is high level design keep it high level, don't delve in details. eg for a videogame: Graphics, Audio, Network, etc, and how they will interact (Interfaces), don't define anything smaller, no classes, no methods, main packages/libraries can be done. For hardware architecture you may use a deployment diagram I guess, have each cube represent the hardware of the boxes that will run your code, you aren't prepared for deployment but you can make changes to your initial proposal next iteration if you need.

Database design is at the end, but the wiki specifically tells you to only define tables, don't define columns yet. You will define that in the low level detail phase.

Comment: I am following the V-Cycle as developpement process.

Comment: Ok update my reply, I feel you should already have the use cases from previous phases, but if you don't, sure generate them before doing design.

Comment: Ok you are right I haven't generated the use case diagrams in the first phase (writing user requirements document) I have chosen to keep them for analysis and conception of the application.

Comment: Which link to wiki you are talking about ? I haven't provided any link please

Comment: sorry I thought you did, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model_%28software_development%29

Comment: okey, from this wiki page, I can tell you that I finished the step **Requirements analysis**. BUT I am not sure what to do on the next phase !!

Comment: start with software/system's use cases that will solve the requirements, finish with a prototype design, not the full thing, just windows mockups of the forms you expect to build etc

Comment: So use case diagrams are the next step ?!

Comment: yes, but software use cases, not business, business use cases are on the requirements step

Comment: Ok i dont know the difference between business and software use case ? But I will search for that tomorrow. I hope you will be here @gia :)